# Adicionar objeto dentro de um objeto

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lógica

é o seguinte, eu tenho 3 tabelas. Cidades, Orgãos e Motivos. 1 Cidade pode ter vários orgãos, e 1 orgão vários motivos.

Meu problema é que em uma só página tem que aparecer todos os orgãos da cidade e dentro do orgão todos motivos do orgão.
Não estou conseguindo colocar os motivos dentro do orgão, questão de lógica mesmo.

Estou fazendo um ng-repeat dos orgãos que são referenciados a cidade

```
$http.get(base_url + 'controlx/functions/getWhere/orgaos/cidades_id/'
       + $stateParams.cidadeId) // Aqui pega os orgãos referenciado a cidade
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.orgaos = data;
  var i = 0;
  var motivo = [];
  for (let orgao of $scope.orgaos){
    $http.get(base_url + 'controlx/functions/getWhere/motivos/orgaos_id/'+orgao.id) // aqui faz uma repetição referenciado ao orgão.
    .success(function(data) {
      motivo.push(data);
      $scope.orgaos=motivo[i];
      i++;
    });
  }
  console.log(motivo);
  if (data.length === 0) {
    $scope.erro = 'Nenhum Orgão Encontrado';
  }
});
```

Então, estava tentando adicionar os motivos dentro de cada orgão. Mas assim não está funcionando.
Eu queria basicamente é colocar os motivos dentro de cada respectivo orgão ($scope.orgaos). Como se fosse dar um .push, mas não funciona em objetos.

Para entenderem como quero:
[image: Essa foto do sistema.]

Comment: Bom dia @ViníciusVilela, vendo seu código, já consigo ter uma pista do que pode estar dando errado. Mas você pode informar se há algum erro no console? e qual o *output* de `console.log(motivo);`?

Comment: Ele retorna arrays (orgãos) com arrays dentro (motivos)

Comment: e nenhum erro no console?

Comment: Não, sem erro no console

Comment: Eu queria colocar os motivos, dentro de cada respectivo orgão ($scope.orgaos) Como se fosse dar um .push, mas não funciona em objetos.

Comment: O que você recebe das duas requests são arrays? Qual é a estrutura destes dados?

Comment: [http://imgur.com/ZDbPSLG] Isso é o que retorna no console.log(motivo). O primeiro orgão tem 2 motivos e o segundo 4

Comment: O que recebo das requests são objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, como você não postou o *data schema*, vou supor que você recebe um Array de Objetos nas duas requisições. Então você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$http.get(base_url + 'controlx/functions/getWhere/orgaos/cidades_id/' + $stateParams.cidadeId) // Aqui pega os orgãos referenciado a cidade
.success(function(data) {

    /* 
        Supondo que aqui você recebe um Array de Objetos.
        Seria algo assim: 
            [
                { id: 'id_orgao_1' },
                { id: 'id_orgao_2' },
                { id: 'id_orgao_3' }
            ]
    */
    $scope.orgaos = data;

    for (let orgao of $scope.orgaos){
        $http.get(base_url + 'controlx/functions/getWhere/motivos/orgaos_id/'+orgao.id) // aqui faz uma repetição referenciado ao orgão.
        .success(function(data) {

            /* 
                Supondo que aqui você recebe um Array.
                Aqui você cria uma nova chave dentro de cada objeto contendo este Array
            */
            orgao.motivos = data

        });
    }

    console.log($scope.orgaos);
    /*

     Sua estrutura final:

            [
              {
                "id": "id_orgao_1",
                "motivos": [ 
                  "motivo1 do orgao1",
                  "motivo2 do orgao1",
                  "motivo3 do orgao1"
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "id_orgao_2",
                "motivos": [
                  "motivo1 do orgao2",
                  "motivo2 do orgao2",
                  "motivo3 do orgao2"
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "id_orgao_3",
                "motivos": [
                  "motivo1 do orgao3",
                  "motivo2 do orgao3",
                  "motivo3 do orgao3"
                ]
              }
            ]
    */


    if (data.length === 0) {
        $scope.erro = 'Nenhum Orgão Encontrado';
    }
});
```

Comment: Nossa, seu lindo, valeu. Deu certim :3

Comment: @ViníciusVilela Ótimo! Boa sorte no projeto!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo. Seria interessante fazermos um javascript básico mesmo e fazer a lógica funcionar com os objetos, ai poderíamos contribuir mais fácil com a solução do problema e replicarmos localmente

segue script básico que fiz, se puder ajustá-lo conforme sua necessidade poderemos avaliar o problema :)

```
  var orgaos = { "cidade" : ["SP", "RJ"] }

  var i = 0;
  var motivo = [];
  for (let orgao of orgaos.cidade){

      motivo.push('teste');
      orgaos=motivo[i];
      i++;

  }
  console.log(motivo);

</script>
```

Comment: Então, vc entendeu errado, a cidade tem orgãos, e os orgãos tem motivos kk

Comment: meu problema não é sintaxe ou algo assim, é na logica mesmo que não está funcionando.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu acima :)